# Play framework routing not working as expected (migration from 2.3.9 to 2.5.9)

Tags: playframework

Im migrating a play app from 2.3.9 to 2.5.9 and the routing is not working as expected. I get an "Action Not found" when I call 
`GET /api/v1/empresa/215071660012/documentos/entrantes` as showed in this screen:
[Play Action Not found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9a9E.png)

I've tried inserting a compile error on the file and play fails the compilation (as expected).

I't looks like play compiles and generates correctly the reverse router (I checked on target folder) but takes a "default" 4 liner router when running.

Im using `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` configured on `build.sbt`

I've tried activator clean, and deleting target folder as well to force full compilation.

What am I missing here?

My routes file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET      /                                                       com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.Application.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET      /assets/*file                                           controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)


# API


GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/resultados/:fecha                  com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.resultadoDocumentosFecha(rut:String, fecha: String)

POST     /api/v1/empresa/:rut/reporteDiario/:fecha               com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.generarReporteDiario(rut:String, fecha: String, cantReportes:Integer?=1)

# Cambia el Modo de Ejecucion del Sistema
# Modos Validos: NORMAL, CONTINGENCIA 
POST     /api/v1/modo/:modo                                      com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.cambiarModo(modo:String)

# Ejecuta el Set de pruebas de testing
POST     /api/v1/pruebas/testing                                 com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.TestingController.generarPrueba()
# Ejecuta el Set de pruebas de homologacion
POST     /api/v1/pruebas/homologacion                            com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.HomologacionController.generarPrueba()
# Ejecuta el Set de pruebas de intercambio
POST     /api/v1/pruebas/intercambio                             com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.HomologacionController_Intercambio.ingresoSobre() 



# Retorna el Pais
GET      /api/v1/pais/:id                                        com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.PaisesController.getPais(id:Integer)



# Pregunta a la DGI por el rut
GET      /api/v1/rut/:rut                                        com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.EmpresasController.darInformacionRut(rut:String)

# Obtiene la informacion de una Empresa
GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut                                    com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.EmpresasController.getEmpresaByRut(rut:String)

# Retorna la informacion de todas las Empresas
GET      /api/v1/empresa                                         com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.EmpresasController.getEmpresas()

# Carga/Actualiza la informacion de las Empresas a partir el XML provisto por DGI
POST     /api/v1/empresa/cargar                                  com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.EmpresasController.cargarEmpresas(path:String)

# Agrega un CAE a la empresa
POST     /api/v1/empresa/:rut/cae                                com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.EmpresasController.addCAE(rut:String)

# Edita una Empresa
PUT      /api/v1/empresa/:rut                                    com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.EmpresasController.editarEmpresa(rut:String)  

# Crea, registra y envia un nuevo Documento
POST     /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos                         com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.aceptarDocumento(rut:String)

# Reenvia Documento existente
PUT      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos                         com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.reenviarDocumento(rut:String, nro:Integer, serie:String, idTipoDoc:Integer)

# Consulta el resultado de un documento
GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos/resultado               com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.resultadoDocumento(rut:String, nro:Integer, serie:String, idTipoDoc:Integer)

# Obtiene la representacion en PDF del documento
GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos/pdf                     com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.pdfDocumento(rut:String, nro:Integer, serie:String, idTipoDoc:Integer, print:Boolean?=false)

# Anula un documento
DELETE   /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos                         com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.anularDocumento(rut:String, nro:Integer, serie:String, idTipoDoc:Integer)

# Retorna los documentos entrantes para una empresa
GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos/entrantes               com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.getDocumentosEntrantes(rut:String, fecha:String)

# Retorna los documentos entrantes para una empresa
GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/procesarEmailEntrantes             com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.procesarEmailEntrantes(rut:String)


# Envia por correo el documento a la empresa
GET      /api/v1/empresa/:rut/documentos/enviarMailEmpresa       com.bluedot.efactura.controllers.DocumentController.enviarMailEmpresa(rut:String, nro:Integer, serie:String, idTipoDoc:Integer)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `DocumentController.getDocumentosEntrantes` Action?

Comment: There are routes in the image that are not in your routes file, are you sure you are accessing the correct server:port, or maybe for some reason Play is using another routes file because the migration.

Comment: Note that if you go straight from 2.3.x to 2.5.x, the `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` line doesn't do anything. That was only needed in 2.4.x.

Comment: Thanks diedu. Play was using a routes file form a bad migrated library jar. I removed the library route file and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks gpgekko for the clarification.